# php artisan migrate:fresh --seed, send and error

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-seeding

**My Model**

class ProfilerContract extends Model
{
protected $table = 'profiler_contracts';

```
protected $attributes = [
    'contract_type',
    'contract_description',
    'profiler_infos_id',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
];

protected $fillable = [
    'contract_type',
    'contract_description',
    'profiler_infos_id',
];
```

}

**My Factory**

```
public function definition(): array
{
    $profilerIDs = DB::table('profiler_infos')->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $contract_type = ['long-term', 'short-term'];
    return [
        'contract_type' => $this->faker->randomElement($contract_type),
        'contract_description' => $this->faker->realText(300),
        'profiler_infos_id' => $this->faker->randomElement($profilerIDs),
        'started_on' => $this->faker->date,
        'finished_on' => $this->faker->date,
    ];
}
```

[ContractFactory.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhXeu.png)

**My DatabaseSeeder**
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

```
public function run(): void
{
    ProfilerContract ::factory(10)->create();
}
```

}

**The error message i keep recieving**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `profiler_contracts` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `contract_type`, `co ntract_description`, `profiler_infos_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (contract_type, contract_description, profiler_infos_id, created_at, updated_at, shor
> t-term, English!' said the Duchess; 'and most things twinkled after that--only the March Hare had just begun to think about stopping herself before she came rathe
> r late, and the reason so many tea-things are put out here?' she asked. 'Yes, that's it,' said the Caterpillar, just as well. The twelve jurors., ?, 2021-12-13 05:05:03, 2021-12-13 05:05:03))

> NB: The data is generated by fakers

Comment: Please add your factory

Comment: I think your problem is in the database table name `profiler_infos` but you send your data in `profiler_contracts`. So I think it's problem with your database **migration** check the database carefully.

Comment: my migrations and factories worked perfectly unitil i added the $attributes property in the models.